# Conditional row sum

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'd like to sum a column of cells if the corresponding cell on the next column contains a string of any sort. I've tried using `SUMIF` but I can't figure out how to combine it with `ISBLANK` or `ISTEXT`.

For example, in this case the function should output 12.

```
---------
| 5 | x |
---------
| 6 |   |
---------
| 7 | y |
---------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the formula you need

```
 =SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(ISTEXT(B1:B3)),TRUE,A1:A3)
```

### First parameter :

> Range (required) - the range of cells that should be evaluated by criterion.

The formula expects a range. This is why `ISTEXT(B1:B3)` alone doesn't work because it returns a single Boolean `FALSE`.

To return a range, you need to use `ARRAYFORMULA()`
I.E : `ARRAYFORMULA(ISTEXT(B1:B3))` returns this

```
--------
| TRUE | 
--------
| FALSE|
--------
| TRUE |
--------
```

### Second parameter :

> Criterion (required) - the condition to be met

You choose when a value will be `SUM`; in this case it's when `ISTEXT()` returns `TRUE`

### Third parameter :

> Sum_range (optional) - the range in which to sum numbers. **If omitted, then range is summed.**

In our case the range we are testing is different from the range we want to sum.